# planets and star sizes as page scrolls

Tags: scroll, resize

I am a teacher and I am trying to make a page for my students showing the comparative size of the planets and the stars, like in one of those videos that are popular in Youtube.

But I have not been able to solve the problem, the closest I got was using "if window.pageXOffset > 1000" animate width etc. but what I really wanted was for the planets and stars (images) to scroll into view at 100% height and then as the page scrolled towards the right, they´d shrink down till 0% when reaching the left border (left=0px), while the next and next planet scrolled into view (showing 3 or 4 at a time) and so forth. The page should allow the user to scroll back and forth at will.

I tried the transform: scale method but wasn´t successful either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were going the right direction with using `transform: scale()`, and I've taken that and run with it.  See the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2z4djt0o/5/

During a scroll event, we look at each planet and decide what its scale should be depending on where it is relative to the left and right edges of the scrolling viewport.

Comment: Wonderful Patrick! Thank you so much, I am going to give it a try with the images I have and will get back to you, but I believe it is going to be perfect! I thank you in the name of my students! :)

Comment: Amazing how FAST you wrote all that, I feel really humbled...3 days I´ve been trying to make this work and you did it in under 30 minutes...gosh!

Comment: I'm glad it's what you were looking for :)  Thanks for being an awesome teacher who does stuff like this!